# how to use lambda in a for loop?

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, lambda

I want to define a function which takes 2 parameters `(x1, x2)` and iterate over `x1` from `0 to 100` and return the sum of the function.

A simplified version of the results should be like this:

```
f = lambda x1, x2: a*x1 + b*x2
```

`x1` should change in range of `i`, `i = [0, 1, ..., 100]`

```
f1 = f(0, x2) + f(1, x2) + f(3, x2) + ... + f(100, x2)
```

How I can define a function which returns the `f1` function above in the correct format?

I tried below but it didn't work:

```
f = lambda x1, x2: a*x1 + b*x2
f1 = lambda x2: (lambda x1=range(100):f(x1,x2))()
```

Comment: what is `a`, `b` and `x2`? Is `x2` a constant?

Comment: Do you mean `f1 = lambda x2: sum(f(x1,x2) for x1 in range(100))`?

Comment: a and b are constant and x2 is an integral of the modified Bessel function from 0 to x2. Since I want to return a function not a list, I don't want to use constant value for x2.

Answer (score 1):

What is `a` and `b`? I assume constants

Why not use `list comprehension`?

```
a=1
b=2

x2 = 4 # I assume this is a constant

output = [a*x1 + b*x2 for x1 in range(101)] # x1 goes from 0 to 100

print(output)

[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 
71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 
92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108]
```

Alternatively,

```
f = lambda x1, x2: a*x1 + b*x2
f1 = lambda x2: sum(f(x1,x2) for x1 in range(101)) # x1 goes from 0 to 100
```

Comment: Hi Makis,

Thanks for answering my question. Returning a list is not what I'm looking for at this stage, but your second answer most probably works for my problem. Thanks again

Comment: I was not sure what you wanted so I posted 2 answers consider upvoting and accepting my answer. cheers